# Open some links inside iPhone web app others outside

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, web-applications, hyperlink

I'm working on a web app for iOS devices.
I know that by using following code, I can open links for my web app within my web app.

```
var a=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    a[i].onclick=function()
    {
        window.location=this.getAttribute("href");
        return false
    }
}
```

Now I have the following problem that there are multiple links that I want to open outside of my web app e.g. "sms:1-23-456". Is there anyone who knows a way to let some links open up outside my web app and still be able to open the remaining inside the app?

Comment: are you talking about standalone web apps? 
what kind of links would you like to open outside your web app?

Comment: Yes I'm talking about standalone web apps. One of the links I want to open outside the web app to make it work is < a href = "sms:0496123123" > when all the links open inside the web app let's say extra pages, this one does too and won't work on as it's supposed to

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard way to do that. you can add a custom attribute to the anchor tag like this

```
<a hfre="www.example.com" openExternally="yes">Test</a>
```

and then check for that attribute in your code

```
if(a[i].openExternally="yes") {
    return true;
} else {
    window.location=this.getAttribute("href");
    return false;
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the URL scheme:

```
var url =this.getAttribute("href")
If(url.startsWith("http")) {
  window.location = url;
  return false;
}
Else {
  return true;
}
```